# setTimeout with 0ms needed to remove animation class

Tags: javascript, css, animation, settimeout

I have a simple animation class in css:

```
.slides-animation {
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

So I can toggle it in a div with `classList.add` and `classList.remove`. It's normaly active, but I want to remove it, call a function and add it again.

```
element.classList.remove("slides-animation");
moveNow(element); // Update the translate(x,y) coordinates of the element.
element.classList.add("slides-animation");
```

But it didnt work as expected. The animation is still there. I managed to remove it by adding a timeout this way:

```
element.classList.remove("slides-animation");
moveNow(element); // Update the translate(x,y) coordinates of the element.
setTimeout(function(){element.classList.add("slides-animation")}, 0)
```

Now, the element will translate to a new (x,y) with no animation. How is this working ?

I have read that by using timeout in this way you will assure that one function will be executed after the other. But, how was the class added again before `moveTo(element)`returned ?

Comment: When removing and adding the same class within the same "cycle" without a browser repaint, nothing happens, as expected, javascript doesn't even remove the class, because that line has already been overwritten by the time it gets to executing it.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/